# Showing 99 notification when a a new notification comes

Tags: bug, status-completed

On Stackoverflow, whenever a new notification comes and I refresh the web page, for some seconds, it shows 99 notifications and then change to 1.

I did not get a chance to take a screenshot, but I am trying. I will post the screenshot as soon as I will get.

Comment: Yep, noticed that myself.

Comment: *♪ You got 99 notifications but it's all just one. ♪*

Comment: I saw that about an hour ago, you're not imagining it ;)

Comment: Will *someone* post a screen shot then? :P

Comment: Repro - When you have one (or more) notifications, refresh the page. A 99 will turn to 1. (using Chrome here)

Comment: @Lix - It appears for something like a fraction of a second. Difficult to capture.

Comment: @ode - ah... I see.. in that case [never mind...](http://i.imgur.com/cNwdK.png) ;) **Felix** - if you want [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ckzTr.png)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what happens when you mixup Min & Max.

Desired behavior is only showing *up to* 99 notifications, not *only more than* 99 notifications.

A fix for this will go out with the next build.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/534/ obligatory xkcd alt text. If ever you replace Jon Skeet with AI, keep in mind :P

Comment: Is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135579/153355) the same bug, or a new one?

Comment: This has just happened to me: so still awaiting the next build?

Comment: Ditto. (9 more)