# The Heinz notification bug strikes again

Tags: bug, status-declined, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing 99 notification when a a new notification comes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134802/showing-99-notification-when-a-a-new-notification-comes)

I just received **a whoppin’ *57* notifications**, and yet none of these appear to be new, nor even duplicated.  This smells like the same bug that [someone else just reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135574/153355) an hourish ago, but which somehow got closed without being addressed.

This is not a joke bug report.  I’m serious.  And it appears I am not alone. So what’s up, doc?

Comment: I got​​​​​​ 99.

Comment: I got​​​​​​ 269.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a side effect of waaaaay too many moderator election reminder notifications going out.

The actual notices have been removed, but the counts on everyone's notifications are going to be a little off until they're cleared (by viewing).

Since it's rather difficult to fix, very localized in time, and self-repairing I'm just gonna let this shake itself out.  It shouldn't happen again.

Comment: In other words, we want a bit for the system to, ahem, catsup?