# Getting old badge notifications and many others again

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Heinz notification bug strikes again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135579/the-heinz-notification-bug-strikes-again)

Today i got 87 notifications, dont know the reason exactly, can you please let me know, why? Please look at the Caucus badge notifications which i got on 8th june and already got the notifications for the same badges. So **why i got notification today again?**

[image]

**Caucus badge notification (8th june):**

[image]

Comment: I experienced the same behavior. It might be related to the moderator election notification.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes it may be related to the moderator election notification but then it must be only 1st line. you can see 1st line in above image.

Comment: @PareshMayani , me too had the same notification..

Comment: @Arjan: If you read the answer to the one I linked, he says **they're not going to fix it**. They're just going to leave the counts for users to clear out manually. All the *actual* duplicate notifications have been removed, though.

Comment: Nope, @animuson, it's not about seeing a zillion notifications. (I thought so too, and hated seeing so many thins closed and deleted, but while editing realized I was wrong. This is about something else, I think.)

Comment: @Arjan: Ah, I see. Probably just a side-effect of the notifications bug. In that case, I don't see what the problem is, as viewing them will mark them as viewed again. So what's the problem?

Comment: (Please use uppercase "I" in "I do" and all. Thanks.)

Comment: Oh, it might be related after all, as it's 87 in total, @animuson. Then indeed something that has been reported and [tagged completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134802/showing-99-notification-when-a-a-new-notification-comes), or [closed as a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135579/the-heinz-notification-bug-strikes), as [too localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135574/99-notifications) or [even deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135557/whats-with-all-these-election-notifications) (not nice when you know for sure you saw it earlier...!)

Comment: Just a wild guess: the global inbox most likely just takes your notification count and highlights that many notifications down the list as "new" and then resets your notification count to zero. So it only *appears* that you're being re-notified on these, when actually the [fake notifications about the election were removed, but the count was not reset](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135581). It's a very minor inconvenience that can be fixed by simply viewing the notifications inbox.

Comment: Nice, Sherlock, errr, @animuson!