# Primary Elections begun, and no notifications

Tags: discussion, notifications, election

Though, there's an open discussion on [Should the primary phase of the election be eliminated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136944/212576); I'd still like to know **why was there no notification on the starting/commencement of elections for Primary phase of elections?**

There are many users who still aren't much used to the working of StackExchange network and sending those red-callout boxed notifications in the top-left corner is the best way to notify them about events such as [Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/).

Comment: Did you visit the election page before during the nomination stage? [I was notified yesterday](http://i.imgur.com/aksN3Sm.png) of the start of the primary.

Comment: @Bart Yes, I did visit it the nominations nearly 40 minutes after the elections were announced.

Comment: @Bart I also visited the page in the nomination stage but I never got a notification highlight (red circle).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps there is an additional requirement. Don't know if you should have "participated" somehow? Comments and such? Or maybe the system just doesn't like you @J.Steen ;)

Comment: I realise now that notifications don't have the red highlight, they have the **hardly visible** blue highlight.

Comment: @Bart The system never likes me. I don't abuse it enough.

Comment: I got notifications for the SciFi election and I hadn't even visited the site in months, so I don't think activity on the election is involved.

Comment: @J.Steen And I think even they aren't shown, when you have the red circle displayed.

Comment: well, I have not participated, but only upvoted some comments and I got a notification (while I didn't saw that notification, I just saw him because of this question). I think the color of the notification should be much more visible.

Comment: They should have just sent out 99 notifications [like they did last time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134802/showing-99-notification-when-a-a-new-notification-comes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you didn't get any for some reason, but there have been notifications for each step of the election so far (check out the below screen shot). Is it possible you just missed them?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was in the notifications box, but the red-circle highlight was never shown regarding it. Also, I noticed the notifications tab just now, after checking the screenshot.

Comment: @BackinaFlash Ah, it will have shown. But it's not your usual red highlight. It's a more subtle one which you might have missed.

Comment: @BackinaFlash That red circle only shows up for 'Inbox' items. You get a different highlight for 'Notifications'

Comment: @BackinaFlash - If you had more than 1 notification (such as an answer/comment on a post) they both go away together. Maybe that was the case?

Comment: @Bart "Subtle" - try "nearly invisible". =D

Comment: I *never* look at these notifications unless they're direct responses (which show up with a red circle). Will there not be a banner this year?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Do you mean like the box on the right hand side of that screen shot under Ask Question?

Comment: I did have some notifications about some comments and answers on my other posts, but their wasn't **any** kind of other box/circle related to notifications tab. Appraently, not even for the edit on [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/170163/revisions)

Comment: @Pekka웃 The request for a banner for elections was declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134789/for-moderator-elections-bring-back-the-system-banner-and-put-in-the-community

Comment: I asked for this last year too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/create-a-permanent-link-to-the-electionarea-during-electiontime