# No notification for dba.SE elections

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, notifications, election

Similar to my last question: [Primary Elections begun, and no notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170208/212576) about elections, this time I received no notifications until today about the community moderator selection on [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election).

While, on the other hand, I received all notifications for the election over on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/election).

Here is a history of notifications from 6th May:

[image: sscap]

<sub>Excuse my MS Paint skillz</sub>

Comment: I only received the final vote notification for Server Fault. I'm curious what the actual criteria are for when it generates a notification. Maybe there's something else that's taken into account? Or maybe it's just a plain boring bug.

Comment: @animuson see my new answer - it's the same deal as hjpotter92.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elections usually have three phases: Nomination, Primary and Election, and we send notifications out to users that can participate in each phase.

The Nomination phase requires 300 rep (3000 on Stack Overflow) to create a nomination and run for moderator.  Because you had less than 300 rep on DBA, you didn't get the notification.

On all sites, the Primary and Election phases require 150 rep to cast votes in.  Since you had more than 150 rep, you were eligible to receive those notifications.

However, the **Primary phase can be entirely skipped** if there are less nominations than we wanted in the final Election phase.  For example, we usually want at most 10 candidates in any election.  Because there were only 3 nominees in the current 2013 DBA election, we moved right to the Election phase and no Primary notifications were issued.

So your notification history looks correct - you should have only received one notification for the DBA election, the final "Please cast your vote" one.