# Why don't we receive notifications for nomination phase while eligible to "vote"?

Tags: discussion, notifications, election

As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181183/), users don't receive notifications for nomination phase of elections if they are not eligible to nominate themselves. It made sense to me at first glance, but later didn't.

Users eligible to vote are still interested in other nominees. Why should they wait (or be unnotified) until primary/election phase to read candidates' introductions?

Wouldn't it be beneficial to know candidates in advance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification/319354#319354).   > "The nomination phase of a moderator election starts and you have enough reputation (300 on most sites, 1000 on Mathematics, or 3000 on Stack Overflow) to nominate. ".

Comment: @Rob That in no way answers _why_.  The asker clearly understands the requirements.  They're looking for an explanation of _why_ those are the requirements (and discussing if those are _good_ requirements).

Comment: Ryan, it's the FAQ; and whys are provided for some of the reasons, it's not support but a discussion - good thing you didn't show up an hour later or this would be closed. --- We'll also presume you are opposite of what the OP wrote: "It made sense to me at first glance, but later didn't." - You are welcome to add a different duplicate, that improves upon @Glo answer, were you left no comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the nomination phase starts, there are no candidates. Sending a notification to 150-300 reputation users would be kinda noisy; they can't *do* anything at that moment. If they're really interested in the site, they'll also see an election is going on in the sidebar widget.

When the election phase starts, you have (usually) 8 days to get to know the candidates, which should be enough to make a solid decision.